# Face a company which you ghosted previously for baseless reason

Tags: job-search, job-offer, career-development

I am a junior developer working in not so common tech field/job like Data scientist or application developer but a good niche where I enjoy. (can't reveal it for some reason)

I was looking to switch job for some reason luckily was referred through a friend to a startup which is making a product I would like to work on.
The interview was great but the salary offered was barley higher than what I currently draw but low enough for my expectations and technologies I have worked on. They said if it would have been a position for software development they would have increased their paygrade. I was very much turned off, why does this field even exist? Or why are you even hiring then while your company is based on this field?

The notice period for my company was 45 days and they were looking for an immediate joiner. I applied for resignation at my company and was waiting for an offer letter(Mistake #1: Applying for resignation before offer letter in hand).
I wanted to leave the current company (for some reason) I didn't think much and was serving the notice period.

I didn't get an offer letter so I called after a week for which they said since they want immediate joiners, they are still looking for other candidates.
After a month I got a call stating I didn't respond back for an offer letter sent to me. I never received any offer letter nor did they sent any(which they accepted later). They said they have sent on the same user but the different domains. Luckily I have my account on both the domains and didn't find any.
I received a message 2 days before the expected joining date stating that my last date is approaching, update us. I was severely ill and said I won't be able to respond back now.

After that I didn't get back to them as I was frustrated with illness, the lower salary offered and the statement they made regarding my field. I also didn't respond to a phone call by them. (Mistake #2: Ghosting hurts professionally Mistake #3: Got hurt by my ego).

This company is incubated and their parent company is hiring now. If I apply there, they definitely would consult their incubated company which I know they do and would have to face this company.
What do I need to do in such a case? I didn't contact them for a month. 
Do I need to contact this company first and ask if they are ready to increase the salary? Directly apply in this parent company? Forget this organization and look for new opportunities working on mistakes I realized?

Edit:

I don't have any legitimate reply for what happened at their child company and it sounds so unreliable for them to have me there is my worry.

Primary reasons I am still over it are:

- I think it is a good startup and I will have a good exposure there.
- I couldn't find any good company at my place and possibly would have to relocate. Relocating isn't an issue but it may take a month or two to settle.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why would you like to join this company? Based on your story, you had an absolutely terrible experience with them already.

Comment: @Bilkokuya What I got from the text was that OP ghosted the company, not the other way around: "After that I didn't get back to them as I was frustrated with illness, the lower salary offered and the statement they made regarding my field. I also didn't respond to a phone call by them."

Comment: About the issues with your fields, both Data Scientist and Application Developer are very common, and particularly the first one is very different from Software Developer. There are many other related titles such as Software Engineer, and while they may seem similar, they have a few important differences.

Answer (score 4):

> If I apply there, they definitely would consult their incubated company which I know they do and would have to face this company.

That would require a higher level of HR organizational skill than most places have, so unless the company is small enough for them to go ask the relevant people personally, don't worry about it.

My friend worked at a major company which hired an engineering position 4 times as the HR representatives assigned to do the hiring kept on quitting (just a sequence of bad luck and a major tech giant targeting them for harvesting). They used all the typical HR systems like Taleo and Workday.

If they are a typical company, he says that using a different email and short form of your name (or perhaps adding a middle name) would be enough to defeat the system.

Heck, I interviewed at certain companies multiple times with the same interviewers and they don't remember me. Unless you made a bozo eruption, you just are not that memorable. I would use the basic email/name countermeasures and just apply.

Comment: As a remark, feel free to incorporate anything of it, if you wish: Even if some records turn up, that's very likely just a non-issue of "didn't work out with him last time" except if there is a single HR person that was similarly personally hurt for some reason, which is unlikely. They have to deal with that often enough and from the sounds of it, it was a wild time at their HR department anyway so they might not have a lot of documentation and/or not put too much value on it.